# MVC Diagram - Two views for one controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Basically, I've been asked to draw up an MVC diagram for an application which will soon fire off into a project and already I'm a little confused.

I need to draw a basic MVC diagram (no problem), but the application can display two views of it's data; but only one view at a time.

I'm having difficulty finding any examples of this on the web, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. You need an example of a diagram with 2 views? Here is a UML model: http://www.irit.fr/~Remi.Bastide/Teaching/Java/MVC/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, you can have a view that **displays** the data and one that **allows you to edit** it. That's two views of the same data. For this you'd have two actions.

Assuming it was a User Profile, you'd have something like:

```
public class UserProfileController
{
    public ActionResult View(int userID) 
    {
        //populate model
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(int userID)
    {
        //populate model
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Then you'd have 2 different views, View might look something like:

```
@model UserModel

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.UserName)

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FirstName)
```

Then edit would be something like:

```
@model UserModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserName)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName)

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```